# Why so many Debug Logs with "setHandshakeSuccess" in vertx / quarkus?

Tags: netty, quarkus, vert.x

we are evaluating quarkus and deployed one prototype with the log level DEBUG and just let it run for a few days. Our Logstash collapsed because of a `java.lang.ArithmeticException` and while investigating we saw so many `setHandshakeSuccess` logs from the new quarkus-web-service.
To be exact: **2600 logs every 5 minutes**.

**No one even uses the web service**. It should be running idle and not produce so many logs.
Can anyone tell us whether this is normal behavior?

Example Log:

```
"message": "[id: 0x9869d583, L:/XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8181 - R:/XX.XXX.X.XXX:49892] HANDSHAKEN: protocol:TLSv1.3 cipher suite:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"

"SourceClassName": "io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler",
"Thread": "vert.x-eventloop-thread-1",
```

The port number at the end of the second ip varies but there is no network traffic.
Does this message only mean that quarkus is checking ALL OF the available ports for traffic?

quarkus.platform.version = 2.8.1.Final

Comment: Consider switching the `io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler` category to level `INFO` instead of `DEBUG`.

Comment: Hey, thank you, yes we already did that but still the question is there: What triggers those debug logs? Is it normal behaviour?

Comment: The method which logs this event may be invoked multiple times for one successful handshake. But thousands of invocations in 5 minutes sounds a lot for an idle application indeed. This could be a bug. Or are you sure there's no proxy misconfigured that might test liveliness a lot by creating connections?